# Trouble with Selenium and java Locating Element

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to locate an element but it always defines as not found 
Below is the HTML code for the section. 
I have tried all the options provided by Selenium IDE, Firebug etc, and cannot get the button to click

```
<section id="page-content" class="content-bordered">
  <section class="content">
  <div class="1stColumn-75">
  <div class="2ndColumn-25">
       <div id="new-customer-btn" class="not-old-btn">
            <a class="btn primary with-icon right" href="./new-btn.html">
                <i class="icon icon-user-add"></i>
                   Criação Clients
             </a>
         </div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try By.Linktext("Criação Clients")

Comment: @jorge Can you consider showing your work please? Thanks

Comment: NOt found mean what? where do you not getting the element in Firebug or in IDE. Are you getting any error? This is simpal xpath `.//*[@id='new-customer-btn']/a` for that element try and let me know

Answer (score 0):

if you can;t find it by " all the options provided by Selenium IDE, Firebug etc"
I think this page section is in a frame or iframe. what you need to do is
to switch to this frame and then try to locate it